# ifstream get line change output from char to string

Tags: c++, ifstream

C++ ifstream get line change getline output from char to string

I got a text file.. so i read it and i do something like

```
char data[50];
readFile.open(filename.c_str());

while(readFile.good())
{
readFile.getline(data,50,',');

cout << data << endl;

}
```

My question is instead of creating a char with size 50 by the variable name data, can i get the getline to a string instead something like

```
string myData;
readFile.getline(myData,',');
```

My text file is something like this

Line2D, [3,2]
Line3D, [7,2,3]

I tried and the compiler say..

no matching function for getline(std::string&,char)

so is it possible to still break by delimiter, assign value to a string instead of a char.

Updates:

Using

```
while (std::getline(readFile, line))
{
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

IT read line by line, but i wanna break the string into several delimiter, originally if using char i will specify the delimiter as the 3rd element which is

readFile.getline(data,50,'**,**');

how do i do with string if i break /explode with delimiter comma , the one above. in line by line

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: @billz yes it say no mention function for getline(std::string&,char)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(readFile, line, ','))
{
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

Always check the result of read operations immediately otherwise the code will attempt to process the result of a failed read, as is the case with the posted code.

Though it is possible to specify a different delimiter in `getline()` it could mistakenly process two invalid lines as a single valid line. Recommend retrieving each line in full and then split the line. A useful utility for splitting lines is [`boost::split()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3331724).

Comment: @mhjd, good answer but maybe you could also say something about why the OP code `while(readFile.good())` is wrong

Comment: @hmjd , now i get it line by line, but if i want to break it by delimiter ,  with the value is stored in string, how do i proceed

Comment: @user1777711 I think the best way is to get it line by line. Once you have one line you have to write *string parsing* code to break it up how you want to break it up. There's no quick way to do this, you just have to write the code.